# PCL: Populate Organized PointCloud by Index

Tags: c++, loops, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, pcl

I have worked with PCL for a few days now, but cannot get around one Problem:
I got a dense, organized `PointCloud<PointT> cloud_1` and want to populate a second, new `PointCoud` `PointCloud<PointT> cloud_2` with processed Points.
So my idea was (in pseudocode, but of course I can provide MWE if it helps):

```
//cloud_1 is also a Ptr that gets a Cloud loaded from PCD File
PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloud_2(new PointCloud<PointT>)

void populateSecondCoud(PointCloud<PointT>& cloud_1, PointCloud<PointT>& cloud_2){
  cloud_2.width = cloud_1.width;
  cloud_2.height = cloud_1.height;

  for (i in cloud_1.height){
    for(j in cloud_1.width){
      PointT p = cloud_1.at(i,j);
      // do processing with the point...
      cloud_2.at(i,j) = p
    }
  }
}
populateSecondCloud(*cloud_1, *cloud_2)
```

This terminates with :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

I guess, because the points-vector of `cloud_2` is still completely empty.
Is there any way to iteratively populate an organized `PointCloud`?

All of that happens for a lot of `PointCloud`s, that is why I try to prevent copying `cloud_2` from `cloud_1` before processing the points.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Of course I can provide a compiling code snippet, but I thought the problem gets clear from above pseudocode.

**Edit:** Clarified how  `cloud_2` is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code:

**1. Memory allocation:**
You need to allocate `cloud_2` with the proper size.
There is a [`pcl::PointCloud` constructor](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/singletonpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#ab5892ddcac7bafdcf659551846ac6aae) that accepts the width and height and allocates the data accordingly, e.g.:

```
PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloud_2 = PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloud(
               new PointCloud<PointT>(cloud_1.width, cloud_1.height));
```

You can also use the [`pcl::PointCloud::resize`](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#a09a0de19c29af92d1ba70b509a256e5a) method to resize `cloud_2` with new width and height inside `populateSecondCoud`:

```
cloud_2.resize(cloud_1.width, cloud_1.height);
```

**2. Proper indexing:**
As you can see in the [`pcl::PointCloud::at` documentation](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/singletonpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#a930c2d1f3d8682ca228873ce1c5cc7c4),
the arguments for `at` are **column, row** (in that order).
You actually pass them in the reverse order, because your `i` in the row index and `j` the column index.

Therefore change lines containing:

```
at(i, j)
```

To:

```
at(j, i)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your Help!
I added the Information how cloud_2 is initializied. I also tried it with passing the Size to the Constructor, which did not help unfortunately.
Also, I think you are right, I will switch the indices, but since the problem already occurs at (0,0) I think it does not fix the termination

Comment: Did you try: `PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloud_2 = PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloud(new PointCloud<PointT>(cloud_1.width, cloud_1.height));` ? or is `cloud_1` dimension not available at this point in time ?

Comment: I added info about the `resize` method that you can also try if you cannot use the ctor.

Comment: Actually it is not, but to try it out I just hardcoded something in. It does indeed work! I had another cloud_2.clear() called somewhere before, that's why it got lost again. Thanky you very much!

Comment: Maybe using `resize` is better than. Please try that as well (see in my updated answer).